# How to access files from within a cloud web service?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, cloud

How do you access local files from within a windows azure web service? I tried routing the complete path to the file within VS but it says that access is denied. I was hoping there was something similar to Server.MapPath() in ASP.NET but I haven't come accross anything like that yet. Also I am running VS in Administrator mode. Any ideas?

NOTE: I am using a WCF Service (A cloud project in VS)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things are different in Azure. Basically you need to indicate and set up local storage usage in the service definition file for your role. There is Local Storage section in the role properties. Once setup, you can access the local storage in your code by calling [RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.getlocalresource.aspx) and passing in the local storage name. You can then read from and write to that local storage. Below are some blogposts on the topic.

- [Windows Azure Local File Storage - How To Guide and Warnings](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/post/Windows-Azure-Local-File-Storage-How-To-Guide-and-Warnings.aspx)
- [Learning Azure Local Storage with me](http://vkreynin.wordpress.com/2010/01/10/learning-azure-local-storage-with-me/)

Comment: is there anyway to check if the files are written there successfully. If so where can I access it?

Comment: You can try to read what you write or check file existence by File.Exists. However, note that local storage is not a durable storage or you can share with other instances. You can lose the contents if you take down a role. If you are looking for a durable and shared storage, you need to consider Azure blob or table storage. There is also Azure Drive  http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Whitepapers/DurableDriveWithNTFSCloud/default.aspx.